# Tor error and usage

Tags: tor, vidalia

I am using Tor and vidalia for privacy,When it opens it shows the dialog[image]

On seeing the log it shows

[image]

I think that ,I was not included in that control area.What I should do for adding me(my Username) to /var/run/tor.

Is there any apps that useful for privacy,anti-surveillance, anti-censorship ..?

Answer (score 0):

This means that somewhere Tor is already started and is binding the 9050 port (could be another application, but it's less likely). To fix the problem, you should stop the other instance of Tor and prevent that it starts before Vidalia.

Answer (score -1):

The default configuration of tor should not give you such a message.

Try to download the package from the tor website and use default config.

Comment: I recommend expanding this to link to the website and explain how to use default configuration.